# How to traverse a graph where a node has multiple parents and sum up values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am receiving this data from a JSON export:

```
nodes = [
    {id:1,data:29,parentOf:[]},
    {id:2,data:31,parentOf:[1,8,7]},
    {id:3,data:41,parentOf:[2,1]},
    {id:4,data:89,parentOf:[3,2,1]},
    {id:5,data:71,parentOf:[4,3,2,1,9,2,8,7]},
    {id:6,data:11,parentOf:[5,4,3,2,1]},
    {id:7,data:59,parentOf:[]},
    {id:8,data:43,parentOf:[7]},
    {id:9,data:97,parentOf:[2,8,7]}
]
```

This is a data structure from a graph where a a node can have zero or more parents. The graph has been flattened for export into the **nodes** array.
Now, i need to aggregate the values of the **data** field.

How can i traverse this graph to get the total sum of data for each node?

EDIT: the final result for the example provided shall be as follows:

```
[
    {id:1,sum:29},
    {id:2,sum:162}, // 31+102+29
    {id:3,sum:203}, // 41+162
    {id:4,sum:292}, // 89+203
    {id:5,sum:622}, // 71+292+259
    {id:6,sum:633}, // 11+622
    {id:7,sum:59},
    {id:8,sum:102}, // 43+59
    {id:9,sum:259}  // 97+162
]
```

EDIT 2: this is a drawing of the graph resulting from the data structure above, made by me:

[image]

I see now, in the parentOf array of the nodes, there is some redundant information.

Despite the fact that the provided example has just only node without parents (id:6), i'm searching a solution to handle the normal case where the nodes without parents are more than one. So i think the graph traversal should start from the leaf nodes, i.e. id:1 and id:7.

A non-recursive approach (if possible) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The challenge here is not in the calculation of the sums, but to interpret what is redundant and what is not.

Comment: Why does node with id `3` have `[2,1]` under it's children (only left branch of 2), and 9 has the right `[2,8,7]`?

Comment: I'm not sure if im asking this late, but how can I draw a graph out of an array such as that? I have the same array with nodes of parentIds array, cant seem to figure out how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes this question hard, is that the `parentOf` lists sometimes not only contain the *id* values of direct children, but also (some) of more remote descendants. So the true graph is not directly apparent.

For instance, the sample data lists node 9 as parent of nodes 2, 8 and 7. Yet the image shows that of those only 2 is a direct child of 9, while 8 and 7 are more distant descendants. Node 1, which is also a descendant of 9, is not listed in the `parentOf` property of node 9.

The information of which are truly direct children *can* be deduced from the data as it is given, but it requires some work. Yet, this information is needed to be able to calculate the sums correctly.

Note that as a consequence of this kind of redundant input, it is impossible to define a triangle in the graph. Let's say node A has nodes B and C as children, and node B has node C as child: such a triangle will not be encodable in the above data structure, as the link between A and C will be considered as a redundant "grandchild" link.

In the solution I present here, I have used [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for recording the descendants and direct children, as this allows for faster look-up than arrays do.

I also created a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for making the nodes accessible by their *id*. Again, this is for performance reasons.

When a cycle is detected in the graph, an exception will be thrown.

As requested, the algorithm does not rely on recursion.

Here is the code:

```js
function sumTree(nodes) {
    // Take copy of nodes array, so that the original is not mutated
    var nodes = nodes.map( node => ({
        id: node.id,
        childrenSet: new Set(node.parentOf), // convert to Set for fast look-up
        childrenSet2: new Set(node.parentOf), // copy 
        descendantSet: new Set(node.parentOf), // Will contain ALL descendants
        sum: node.data
    }) );
        
    // For faster lookup, create a Map with nodes keyed by their node.id.
    var hash = new Map(nodes.map( node => [node.id, node] ));

    // Create complete descendants set for each node
    nodesCopy = nodes.slice();
    while (true) {
        // Get index of first node that has no (more) children
        let i = nodesCopy.findIndex(node => !node.childrenSet.size);
        if (i < 0) break; // Not found: then we're done
        let id = nodesCopy.splice(i, 1)[0].id; // extract found node id
        nodesCopy.forEach(parent => {
            if (parent.childrenSet.has(id)) { // Found a parent of it
                // Extend the parent's descendant list with the node's one
                parent.descendantSet = new Set([...parent.descendantSet, 
                                                ...hash.get(id).descendantSet]);
                // Don't consider this node any more. 
                // At one point the parent may become a leaf
                parent.childrenSet.delete(id);
            }
        });
    }
    if (nodesCopy.length) throw "Exception: graph has cycles";

    // Create true children sets (only direct children, without "redundancy"):
    nodes.forEach( node => {
        node.childrenSet = new Set(node.childrenSet2);
        [...node.childrenSet]
            // Collect descendants of children
            .reduce( (remote, id) => 
                new Set([...remote, ...hash.get(id).descendantSet]), new Set() )
            // Remove any of those from the children's set
            //   (so no more "grand" children there)
            .forEach( id => node.childrenSet.delete(id) ); 
    });

    // Calculate the sums bottom-up
    nodesCopy = nodes.slice();
    while (true) {
        let i = nodesCopy.findIndex(node => !node.childrenSet.size);
        if (i < 0) break; 
        let leaf = nodesCopy.splice(i, 1)[0];
        nodesCopy.forEach(parent => {
            if (parent.childrenSet.has(leaf.id)) {
                parent.sum += leaf.sum;
                parent.childrenSet.delete(leaf.id);
            }
        });
    }

    // Only return the information we need
    return nodes.map( node => ({ id: node.id, sum: node.sum }) );
}

// Sample data
var nodes = [
    {id:1,data:29,parentOf:[]},
    {id:2,data:31,parentOf:[1,8,7]},
    {id:3,data:41,parentOf:[2,1]},
    {id:4,data:89,parentOf:[3,2,1]},
    {id:5,data:71,parentOf:[4,3,2,1,9,2,8,7]},
    {id:6,data:11,parentOf:[5,4,3,2,1]},
    {id:7,data:59,parentOf:[]},
    {id:8,data:43,parentOf:[7]},
    {id:9,data:97,parentOf:[2,8,7]}
];

// Calculate sums
var result = sumTree(nodes);

// Output result
console.log(result);
```

Comment: neat and clever the idea to loop until there are no more leafs, this helped me a lot, as there can be more than one leaf and more than one "root" i.e. nodes with no parents.

Comment: Nice to hear you appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm missing something...
Please have a look on what follow:

1. Iterate All Nodes
2. Sum `node.data` with all `parents.data`
3. return an Object with only `id` and `sum` property.

```js
var nodes = [
    {id:1,data:29,parentOf:[]},
    {id:2,data:31,parentOf:[1,8,7]},
    {id:3,data:41,parentOf:[2,1]},
    {id:4,data:89,parentOf:[3,2,1]},
    {id:5,data:71,parentOf:[4,3,2,1,9,2,8,7]},
    {id:6,data:11,parentOf:[5,4,3,2,1]},
    {id:7,data:59,parentOf:[]},
    {id:8,data:43,parentOf:[7]},
    {id:9,data:97,parentOf:[2,8,7]}
];


var result = nodes
  .map((item, i, items) => {
    let r = Object.create(null); 
    
    r.id = item.id;
    
    r.sum = item.parentOf.reduce((prev, next, j) => {
      let parent = (items.filter(x => x.id === next)[0] || {});
      let parentData = parent.data || 0;
      
      return prev + parentData;
    }, item.data);

    return r;
  })
;

console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve, iteration is - with no doubt - the more clean and performat way... Consider that your structure could be circular and fall in an infinite loop... 
Just try to edit my snippet adding a logic that goes up to their parents...